# Field of algebraic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-curves, fields, class-field-theory

We assume $K$ as a field of characteristic zero. By a field of algebraic functions of one variable over $K$ we mean a field $R$ satisfying $R=K(x,y)$ with $x$ being transcendental over $K$, and $R$ is algebraic over $K(x)$.

My question is: Whether there exist a subfield $F \subset R$ and $a \in R$ such that $R=F(a)$ with $a$ being transcendental over $F$. (In the case of rational function fields, this result follows easily.)

Comment: Almost never. $R$ is the field of rational functions on a smooth projective curve $C$ over $K$, and your assertion implies that $C$ has genus $0$. As soon as $g(C)\geq 1$, this will not happen.

Comment: @abx: indeed, if $F$ is assumed to contain $K$. It is possible though that $R$ is non-rational over $K$ but rational over some other subfield, but of course also that doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @ArnoFehm Just to be clear, that cannot happen if $K$ is algebraically closed, correct?

Comment: @Kevin Casto: indeed, can't happen if $K$ is algebraically closed